# Ability to have multiple programmers work on same project

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am working with a small group of developers; we want the ability to be working on the same project at the same time over the internet. Is there a way to do this? I have read into Team Foundation Server but none of us have been successful in creating actual code files. Any suggestions? We are using Visual Studios 2012, C#.

Comment: Are you talking about source control, like [Git](http://git-scm.com/) or [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/)? Or do you mean looking at the same files at the same time?

Comment: Team Foundation Service is the cloud-hosted version. They have free plans for up to 5 developers.  If you have a server, static IP, and VPN capabilities (or server 2012 has an alternative to VPN), you can use Team Foundation Express.  It also has limitations, but the code may technically be more secure locally, while potentially sacrificing speed and availability (due to power outages, etc.).

Comment: We want to have one project with all the source code and each one of us to have the ability to be working in the same project at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in my comment, you can use [Git](http://git-scm.com/) or [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/). I haven't used Visual Studio much lately, but you should be able to integrate Subversion with it pretty easily. I haven't tried Git with Visual Studio, but considering its popularity I bet it integrates rather easily also.

Both of them are means of [source control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_control). Subversion is a simpler interface with a smaller learning curve, but Git uses a distributed model and gives you finer control over the history and progress of your project. Git comes with some visualization tools (gitg, gitk, etc.). You can use a client like [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) for Subversion.

Both of them support using external tools to compare files/projects (diffs), which is a bonus for most Windows users. You can use something like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) for that.

That should be all you need :)

Comment: I haven't encountered a good VS/Git integration yet. Git is rather peculiar, SVN in comparison has a normal checkout-checkin workflow.